# How to unset default value in "Connect to Database" in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Once I thought it would be a great idea to set this field to the database I am working mostly with. I was wrong. Since this database is dropped and restored rather often, each time I am forced to reconnect after the drop.

I have found some recommendations, like setting this value via sql command, but nothing works.

**Reset All** every time is not option cause I am not thinking about it so much and this is annoying too.

Does anyone know where this value is stored to try to unset it: master DB, registry, some file?

Why does MS add a feature to change something without possibility to reset it back? (*rhetoric*)

[image]

**Edit**:
Have uninstalled SQL Server, though a lot of crap remained in the system:
[image]

Uninstalled all of them, installed SQL Server from scratch, this issue remains...

Comment: I'm confused, you do change the setting from that screen (assuming your using registered servers). Considering you've found the screen, why not change it? Unless you mean that it's your Login's setting on the server (and not the setting in SSMS)?

Comment: Every time I open Management Studio and try to connect to SQL Server previously selected database aka dev_database is selected. I can change it to <Default> but it's reset every time.
I click on Connect, several secons later error dialog pops up, so I need to go to Connection Properties and change it.
I would like to have a permanent solution

Comment: Are you closing SSMS properly when you finish with the application? SSMS saves it's settings when you close it (properly). If you don't close it properly those settings likely won't be saved, or if you open a second SSMS (after changing the setting on another) and close that afterward the settings will be overwritten.

Comment: Yes, I do. It normally takes time(some seconds) to close and usually I do not close established connection manually, but crashes happen very seldom. I never run second instance either.

Comment: Not sure, I can't replicate your problem. I would suggest deleting the registered server and adding it again.

Comment: I could even try reinstalling SQL Server, but a lot of things will remain in the system anyway if I do it, this one small thing could stay. With MS you never know...

Comment: Why would uninstalling SQL Server change your SSMS issue? I'll be honest, this is definitely seems more like a user/environment issue, not a bug/"feature" by MS.

Comment: My experience with uninstalling other MS products shows that a lot of stuff remains in the system. But probably I will make a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

Needed to rename/delete file:

```
C:\Users\(USER)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\12.0\SqlStudio.bin
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75d6c722-ddbe-4714-b954-763a496f6f63/how-to-unset-default-value-in-8220connect-to-database8221-in-ssms?forum=sqlgetstarted

https://serverfault.com/questions/278582/ssms-where-does-sql-server-store-its-server-names

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you select the database and press delete, that clears it down.  Connect, then next time it should go back to default. At least it does on SSMS2017 - haven't got older versions installed to check.

OK

Comment: Nope, it doesn't normally work for MS software. I've tried

Comment: which version of ssms are you using?

Comment: 2014 aka 12.0.4487.0